# In my application am using customized list-view with text view and image View. when i am scroll then imageview position is change

Tags: android

I have problem, i am using custom ListView with text view and image View but when i am scrolling the list then image View position is change. i don't know why.when first time list view is load then all thing is ok but when i m scrolling then image view position is chage.

```
please give me any suggestion for this.

/* this is my code */

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EntityList>
    {
        ArrayList<EntityList> entitiesList;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        int Resource;
        // ViewHolder holder;
        ImageView globalImgView;
        private Context context;

        public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<EntityList> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            // this.context = context;
            vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            Resource = resource;
            entitiesList = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) 
        {

            final  ViewHolder holder;
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) 
            {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);

                holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);     
                holder.tvimgview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_mobicon);

                String listName = entitiesList.get(position).getListName();

                Map<String, Bitmap> entityListImgName = HttpHandler.getInstance().getEnitityListImgMap();

                if(entityListImgName.containsKey(listName))
                {
                    Bitmap bmp = entityListImgName.get(listName);
                    holder.tvName.setText(listName);
                    holder.tvimgview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                }


                v.setTag(holder);
            }       

             else 
                {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                }

            try
            {

                String listName = entitiesList.get(position).getListName();
                holder.tvName.setText(listName);        

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception in CustomListAdapter class :" +ex);
            }

            return v;

        }


        static class ViewHolder 
        {

            public TextView tvName;
            public ImageView tvimgview;

        }       

    }
```

Comment: please define "position is changed", you mean it take a different position inside your row? or the loaded image does not belong to the row being displayed?

Comment: use it on inside ths try block String listName = entitiesList.get(position).getListName();

                Map<String, Bitmap> entityListImgName = HttpHandler.getInstance().getEnitityListImgMap();

                if(entityListImgName.containsKey(listName))
                {
                    Bitmap bmp = entityListImgName.get(listName);
                    holder.tvName.setText(listName);
                    holder.tvimgview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                }

Comment: first time image view position in 0th position after scrolling it change on any postion in list view.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (probably) is that, you are putting values in your holder when `v == null`. I refer to this part of your code

```
String listName = entitiesList.get(position).getListName();

Map<String, Bitmap> entityListImgName =     HttpHandler.getInstance().getEnitityListImgMap();

 if(entityListImgName.containsKey(listName))
 {
     Bitmap bmp = entityListImgName.get(listName);
     holder.tvName.setText(listName);
     holder.tvimgview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
 }
```

When using holders, you only need to define views using `findViewById` or inserting values that will be fixed for all your rows when your view is null.

Move or copy that part of code to your `else` block and fill your `ImgView`as you did with your `TextView` and your recycled views will be refreshed when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

```
           String listName = entitiesList.get(position).getListName();

            Map<String, Bitmap> entityListImgName = HttpHandler.getInstance().getEnitityListImgMap();

            if(entityListImgName.containsKey(listName))
            {
                Bitmap bmp = entityListImgName.get(listName);
                holder.tvName.setText(listName);
                holder.tvimgview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
```

Place this code after tvName.settext